# 404 Response from server without request reaching the "doGet"-method

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, get, http-status-code-404

In my Netbeans java web application I have an ajax GET request to the controller.

suddenly, the server started sending 404 Response Messages to every Ajax Request.

What's even weirder is this:

In the controller, the following code is supposed to handle GET requests:

```
 @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest1(request, response);
        } catch (JsonException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

So I set a breakpoint next to this "doGet"method. Then I initiated the GET-request. (Purpose: being able to step through the code step by step in debugging mode).

The thing is: The ajax-request doesn't even arrive at this method. This also means that the server doesn't actually send a response.

However, google chrome is telling me that there was a 404 response:

[image]

What the hell is going on here ??!!

---

UPDATE:

Here's how I mapped the url used by the ajax-GET-eequest to the controller:

```
@WebServlet(
        name = "controller",
        urlPatterns = {"/controller"}    
        )
public class controller extends HttpServlet {

   //
```

(i.e. I used annotations)

Here's the beginning of the ajax-request:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8081/CourseProject/controller";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "get",
        //etc.
```

Comment: you have not correctly mapped the path _/CourseProject/controller_ to your servlet's doGet() method so tomcat does not know how to dispatch the request and sends back a 404

Comment: @P.J.Meisch:  I updated the question ... as you can see from the updated question I used annotations to do the mapping between url and controller ... this worked before ... then suddenly I got all these 404 Responses ...

Comment: I wanted to create a new web project based on the old web project ... so I created a "web application based on existing sources". I thought the files would be copied ... however changes I made in the new project were reflected in the files of the old projects also ... so I deleted the new project again ... the problems started after creating the new project ... But I don't understand what it has to do with anything